# interactivePopGestureRecognizer popToRootViewController instead of popViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, interactivepopgesture

I have a NavigationViewController with multiple ViewControllers.
I set the `navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil`
to enable the swipe to pop functionality. That works as it should.

I have the case in my App where I don't want the user to be able go back to the last ViewController but instead always get back to the "overview" (rootViewController).

Is there any way i can pop to rootViewController instead of popViewController when I do the swipe to pop gesture?

Comment: Once such a viewController is reached, remove all the other viewControllers between this one and the root view controller from the navigation stack.

Comment: i haven't thought about that, that should work! thanks